# What is the proper way to convert first character of a string from upper to lower case in shell scripting on Mac OS?

Tags: string, bash, macos, shell, scripting

What is the proper way to convert first character of a string from upper to lower case in bash on Mac OS
I am not on Bash 4 version to convert string by following command

```
$string="Hello"
echo ${string^}
```

Is there any other alternative way to do it?
Tried these commands too `sed -e 's/./\L&/'` or `sed -e 's/^./\L&\E/'`but didn't worked.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How can it be a duplicate? Firstly the question is about converting them to a lowercase and secondly, none of those answers solve it.
@inian

Comment: Using the first answer, just swap the order of `:lower:` and `:upper:`. There's a comment below the second answer that says how to change it to lowercase.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to reverse the conversion direction of those answers, I don't think you're cut out to be a programmer. You can't always find exact solutions to your problem, you need to learn to generalize and extrapolate.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't said I was a programmer. I am learning things to be a programmer. Still I don't count this as a duplicate, but it can be as a reference.

Comment: We don't require them to be exact duplicates for this close reason, just that they're similar enough that the answers are the same or can be easily extrapolated.

Comment: You shouldn't need to be an expert to understand that you can easily change `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` to `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` to convert in the opposite direction, it should be obvious.

Comment: `${myvar,}` will convert the first character of `$myvar` to lowercase